# What does the phrase "weigh down" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Here is a sentence from an adventure game:

> In the game, you use your enemy's corpse as bridges and to weigh down
>   pressure plates, providing cover from spears-firing traps – sometimes
>   for yourself, and sometimes for blocks need to be kept intact so you
>   can use them as stepping stones.

I am not sure about the function of pressure plates here. How can they provide cover to the player from traps by being weighed down?

Answer (score 1):

To "weigh [something] down" means to put a weight on top of it to push it down.

In your game, if a spear is triggered by the weight being applied to a "pressure plate" on the floor, then having a weight on it continuously could prevent a spear being triggered when the player walks across it.